# Rails: Save values from model to DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using a lot of calculations in my model, e.g. this one:

```
def url
  brandurl = Brand.where(:company => self.brand).pluck(:url)
  brandurl = brandurl.shift.strip
  unique_id = [self.token, self.created_at.strftime('%d%m%y-%H:%M:%SUTC')].join("&")
  self.url = brandurl + "/?utm_campaign=" + unique_id + "&utm_source=" + self.channel1 + "&utm_medium=" + self.channel2
end
```

All I want is to save the value of url to my DB. Neither `before_create` nor `after_create` is working. `self.class.exists?(url: url)` is also not working (creates a loop & webserver crashes). Any tipps are much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use update_attributes.

instead of `self.url=` use update_attributes like this:

```
update_attributes(url: brandurl + "/?utm_campaign=" + unique_id + "&utm_source=" + self.channel1 + "&utm_medium=" + self.channel2)
```